# Globbing shell variable names

Tags: shell, variable

I need to expand some shell (not environment) variable names that are thematically related, e.g. `B2_...` where `...` could be one or more different things like `ACCOUNT_ID`, `ACCOUNT_KEY`, `RESPOSITORY` and so on.

I don't know ahead how many variables there are nor which ones they are. That is what I'm want to find out.

I want to be able to iterate through the `B2...` variables without having to put each individual name in the list, similar to how I would glob filename expansions.

I use zsh for interactive sessions, but solutions for sh or bash are good too.

Comment: This is what associative arrays are for, iterate over the array indices.  Interactively, I guess you could use tab expansion but that's not iteration, that's just a typing shortcut.

Comment: Do you mean you need to list all variables starting name by `B2_` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot  Yes, but but not interactively with <tab>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) :

```
$ foobar_1=x foobar_2=y foobar_3=z
$ for v in "${!foobar_@}"; do echo "$v"; done
```

### Output :

```
foobar_1
foobar_2
foobar_3
```

### 'dereference' :

```
$ for v in "${!foobar_@}"; do echo "${!v}"; done
```

### Output² :

```
x
y
z
```

Comment: I didn't realise ${!foobar_*} worked like that, so I've learnt something new (20 years in *nix shells too <goes to sit in the shame corner>).  And of course `${!v}` gives the value too.

Comment: @NickColeman, note that in bash `${!v}` and `${!x*}` are not related. `${!v}` is bash-specific and different from ksh93's `${!v}` (where it's to query the target of nameref). `${!x*}` comes from ksh93, later copied by `bash`. It's better to use `"${!foobar_@}"` than `${!foobar_*}` unless you can guarantee that no variable name contains any character also found in the current value of `$IFS`.

Comment: Fixed link for bash PE

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using individual variables with names beginning with `B2_`, you could use an associative array (`B2`).  e.g.

Note: the following is specific to `zsh`.  `ksh` and `bash` also have associative arrays, but the syntax for initialising and using them is different (see below).

```
typeset -A B2
# initialise array
B2=(ACCOUNT_ID 12345 ACCOUNT_KEY 54321 REPOSITORY somewhere)

# two different ways of adding elements to the array
B2[FOO]=bar
B2+=(NAME fred)             

for key val in ${(kv)B2}; do 
  echo "$key: $val"
done
```

Output for that example would be:

```
ACCOUNT_KEY: 54321
FOO: bar
REPOSITORY: somewhere
ACCOUNT_ID: 12345
NAME: fred
```

You can also print the entire array (in a form suitable for re-use in a script or on the command line) with `typeset -p`:

```
% typeset -p B2
typeset -A B2=( ACCOUNT_ID 12345 ACCOUNT_KEY 54321 FOO bar NAME fred REPOSITORY somewhere )
```

---

The same operations in `ksh` or Bash would be as follows:

```
# initialise it
typeset -A B2
B2=([ACCOUNT_ID]=12345 [ACCOUNT_KEY]=54321 [REPOSITORY]=somewhere)

# add elements
B2[FOO]=bar
B2+=([NAME]=fred) 

# get a list of the keys and use them as indexes to get the values
for key in "${!B2[@]}"; do 
  echo "$key: ${B2[$key]}"
done

# print the entire array
typeset -p B2
```

Comment: Interesting ideas. The variables are already set before my script gets to them; I might see if upstream can change to an array.   I like the `typeset -p`.

Answer (score 5):

#### Bash has `compgen -v`.

In Bash, you can list variable names that begin with *`B2`* using:

```
compgen -v B2
```

Running the command `compgen -v text` lists the same variables that are available as autocompletion results when you type `$` followed by *`text`* and then press tab. (You may have to press tab multiple times for them all to be displayed.) You can use `compgen -v` interactively, but you can also use it in a script. For example:

```
$ bash -c 'compgen -v SDK'
SDKMAN_CANDIDATES_DIR
SDKMAN_CURRENT_API
SDKMAN_DIR
SDKMAN_LEGACY_API
SDKMAN_PLATFORM
SDKMAN_VERSION
```

(The script can, of course, be in a file, rather than passed to `bash` as an operand to the `-c` flag.)

The purpose of `compgen` is to perform command completions. See the output of `help compgen` (in Bash) for general information about it. Although this will probably do what you want, you might find that other approaches, such as the parameter expansion technique in [Gilles Quenot's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/431992/11938), more clearly express what you're doing. I can't really say which is better, as this depends on what you are doing and perhaps also on your personal stylistic preferences.

Comment: Great use of compgen, I'm guilty of thinking of all the comp... functions as relevant to interactive completion functions only.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
for var (${(M)${(k)parameters}:#B2_*})
  printf '$%s == %s\n' $var ${(P)var}
```

- `${(k)parameters}` are the *keys* of the `$parameters` special associative array that gives information on all parameters.
- `${array:#B2_*}` *removes* from the `$array` expansion, the elements that match `B2_*`. With `(M)` (for `M`atched), that's reversed: *keep* the elements that match.
- `${(P)var}` (similar to `bash`'s `${!var}`): expands to the value of the parameter whose name is stored in `$var`.

If you want only the variables that are not exported:

```
setopt extendedglob # for ^
for var (${(M)${(k)parameters[(R)^*export*]}:#B2_*})
  printf '$%s == %s\n' $var ${(P)var}
```